# Ninject Mvc Exception Handling at Controller Constructor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, error-handling, constructor, ninject

I have a MVC website that works in local but not on remote server.
The erroneous part is the MVC Webapi which uses ninject on controller's constructors.

The post request reaches the webapi while the webapi is working on local computer, and everything is fine.

However, same post request does not reach any method inside same API working on remote computer, and I need to know why.

My guess is that one of the dependencies fail while being injected by ninject.

Saving exception info inside a text file on remote server will do for now. I will implement a thorough solution later on.

Comment: Ninject interception didn't work, there are multiple kernels.

Comment: I seem to have installed some kind of interception by using ninject extensions . And appended extensions to dependency registers.

Now dependency creations seem to go through the extension , there is a try cache wrapping "invocation.Proceed();"  , the best i could get is .

... does not have a default constructor","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException","StackTrace":"   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)\

Comment: And that exception is not cought by my implemented version of interceptor. Where else should i look. Apparently i need to have some kind of control over "DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator‌​"

Comment: I seem to have gotten more information , moved constructor arguments inside a function and ran them with try cache . this wasnt working before but some fixes here and there enabled it . Im eventually getting some exceptions like null reference . More information would come handy.

Comment: have you implemented Application_Error in your Global.asax? that should handle any unhandled exceptions from your app.

Comment: regarding the error, did you use the Ninject.Web.WebApi package from Nuget? it will register everything you need to properly resolve constructors.

Comment: Yes , its installed . Everything works just fine , only some of the dependencies throw errors while being instantiated and i was looking for a way to see which one. I have managed to find those errors but not by using any property of ninject or asp.net or intercepting etc.  Which is how i should have done .  I will install proper ways to do this later on. Something like remote machine tests etc. Including ninject tests.

Comment: I have implemented Application_Error in your Global.asax as well as other attribute error handlers , controller error handlers, interceptors , none of them did fire. Strange as it gets.

Comment: It's worth showing some of your code, and ideally please also move your above detail to the post, especially errors and any configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Its been a long time, but as i remember , it turned out to be the proxy setting on remote machine.

Multiple api's were talking to eachother via http . 
A proxy setting on remote machine , required authorization for these api's to talk to eachother .

Changing the code resolved the problem , otherwise using the proxy with proper authorization was another solution.

Thanks